# Batch file to logoff Users with exception of some Users

Tags: batch-file

i am new here at Stackoverflow.

I've a problem to ad a exception to a batch file running on our terminal server (windows 2019).

My batch file logoff user with disconnected sessions, but now i have to ad some exceptions for 5 Users.

Can you please help me out?

Thank you very much

`

```
@echo off

REM getrennte Citrix-User abmelden

SET SESSION_PFAD=C:\Windows\Temp\Session.txt

query session > %SESSION_PFAD%

for /f "eol=> skip=2 tokens=1,2,3," %%i in (%SESSION_PFAD%) DO (
    if "%%k" == "Getr."  (
        REM User abmelden
        logoff %%j
    )
)

:END
del %SESSION_PFAD%
```

`

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I solve the Problem with a Whitelist of the AD group, i hope it will help someone :)

```
@echo off
REM getrennte Citrix-User abmelden (ausser Personal - C:\tools\Skripte\Whitelist.txt)

SET SESSION_PFAD=C:\Windows\Temp\Session.txt
if exist "%SESSION_PFAD%" del "%SESSION_PFAD%"
query session | find /i "Getr." | find /v "services" > %SESSION_PFAD%

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in (%SESSION_PFAD%) DO call :_CHECK %%i %%j
goto _END
:_CHECK
    set USER=%1
    set ID=%2
    type "C:\tools\Skripte\Whitelist.txt" | find /i "#%USER%#"
    if not errorlevel 1 goto _END
    echo %User% wird abgemeldet
    echo %date% %time:~0,5% %User% >> "C:\tools\Skripte\Logoff.txt"
    logoff %ID%
:_END
set USER=
set ID=
```

Greets
Daniel